# Count number of special characters [^&$#] appearing in a paragraph

Tags: python

I would like to count the number of special characters `[^&*$]` appearing in a paragraph using python.  Can anyone help me to do this in succinctly?  I don't want to use for loop condition.

Comment: If you don't want loops or comprehensions, then there's a regex option - replace everything but these chars with nothing and take `len()` of the rest.

Comment: `print sum(paragraph.count(x) for x in ['[','^','&','$','#',']'])`

Comment: Life is easy with regex: `text_length = len(re.sub('[A-Za-z0-9\s]+', '', text))`

Answer (score 7):

`Counter` makes a set of all the characters giving an upper bound to the number of iterations.

Given a string of `text`:

```
import string
import collections as ct


special_chars = string.punctuation
sum(v for k, v in ct.Counter(text).items() if k in special_chars)
```

Replace `specials_chars` with whatever characters you wish to count.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a duplicate but you can use regex `re.sub` and len i.e  Replace all the word characters `\w` with `''` so you end up with non word characters or special characters.

```
import re
x = "asdfklsdf#$&^#@!"
new = re.sub('[\w]+' ,'', x)
```

Output : `#$&^#@!`

```
len(new)
7
```

In case you want to count only those characters then

```
new = re.sub('[^\^&*$]+' ,'', x)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using `re.findall`...

If you have an input string of:

```
para = "hello #123 ^@"
```

you can use `re.findall` to get a list of matches to a `regex`. So if we use the `regex`: '[\w]`, we can get a list of all non special chars in the string. Simply then subtract the length of that list from the length of the original string to get the number of special chars:

```
specialChars = len(para) - len( re.findall('[\w]', para) )
```

which returns `3` :)